# the difference between Solr Client and Apache_Solr_Service?

Tags: php, solr

Here is my code which works well:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['btn'])){
    $search=$_POST['search'];
    require_once('Apache/Solr/Service.php');
    $solr=new Apache_Solr_Service( 'localhost', '8983', '/solr' );

     $offset = 0;
     $limit = 10;

     $queries = array(
         'title:*'.$search.'*'
     );
     foreach ($queries as $query) {
         $response = $solr->search($query, $offset, $limit);

         if ($response->getHttpStatus() == 200) {
             // print_r( $response->getRawResponse() );

             if ($response->response->numFound > 0) {

                 foreach ($response->response->docs as $doc) {
                     echo '<pre>';
                     echo 'title ='.$doc->title;
                     echo '<br>';
                     echo 'image='.$doc->image;
                     echo '</pre>';
                 }

                 echo '<br />';
             }
         } else {
             echo $response->getHttpStatusMessage();
         }
     }
}

?>
```

It searches for what `$_POST['search']` is. But I want to use something named `Solr Client`. Because it has a method named `$solrQuery->set('spellcheck','true');` that gives you the "did you mean x ?" feature.

I've followed [this](http://php.net/manual/en/solr.examples.php) from the doc with no success. It throws `SolrClient class not found`.

Any clue how can I use `SolrClient` and what's its different with `Apache_Solr_Service` ?

Comment: They're fundamentally different PHP Solr clients, so you would need to migrate all of your code over to use the other library if you wanted to switch. `Apache_Solr_Service` [supports passing additional parameters to its search method](https://github.com/PTCInc/solr-php-client/wiki/FAQ) though, which might be easier to implement.

Comment: @iainn you mean both `Apache_Solr_Service` and `Solr Client` are two different implementation of the Solr? And you mean using `Apache_Solr_Service` is easier? If yes, does `Apache_Solr_Service` support something for checking typo and suggesting the right word? i.e. "did you mean x?"

Comment: Yes, they're separate PHP Solr client implementations. I don't know too much about Solr, but I think the page I linked should be useful. If you pass the array `['spellcheck' => true]` as the 4th argument to `search` in your code above, it should behave the same as the other library.